# Can i set nodejs viewengine for two or more folders?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, structure

Well this is my file structure.

```
modules  
------------users  
---------------------views  
-----------------------------file.handlebars  
public  
routes  
views  
app.js  
and other folders and files
```

but my problem is that i have two views folders

and i am able to set viewengine only to one folder

```
// View Engine
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine(
  "handlebars",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "layout"
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

is there any way how can i set viewengine to two folders and change in route as i need?

Something like this.

```
router.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("OPTION1/register" , {title: 'Register'});
  }
});

router.get("/hfghf", function (req, res) {
    res.render("OPTION2/hfghgf" , {title: 'hfghgfh'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the multiples views directory as array into it. Working in express 4.x

```
app.set("views", [path.join(__dirname, "views"),path.join(__dirname,'other_views')]);
```